# Why my website is slow only the first time I visit?

Tags: performance, timeout

when I visit my website the first time the access is really slow (not the downloading of the page, only waiting before the access), but after the first time I visit the website the navigation is normal and fast.
Someone can kindly help me making some tests?
Thanks
Alex

Comment: This is because there are no cached information. Caches help websites load faster.

Comment: I thought the same, but I've noticed this behavior happened also in the admin area, where the information are alway different without cache.

Comment: Cache is stored locally.

Comment: could you make a try?

Comment: https://www.nordestyacht.it

Answer (score 0):

Firstly whenever you visit a site for the first time, your local server will resolve the DNS resolution, more precise will translate the page name into an IP address. The upcoming times the IP address is cached(Store onto your PC or your local server).
Secondly has something to do with saving some of the web page data into your device, basically the second the web page content may be already stored into your device, but that depends on the actual website which you are browsing on.

Comment: I've the sensation that could be a delay o bad routing in the htaccess...